# How to send data from child process back to parent using Spawn in NodeJS

Tags: python, node.js, spawn

I'm trying to run a python script from NodeJS using the spawn child process.  I'm able to successfully get python to run and see the data using console log, but can not send the actual data back to the parent function so that I can use it elsewhere.

***This the "Child.js" file where spawn is being called in Node.js:***

```
//Child.js:  Node.js file that executes a python script using spawn...

function run_python_script(jsonString, callback){

    //spawn new child process to call the python script
    const {spawn} = require('child_process');
    const python = spawn('python3', ["-c",`from apps import python_app; python_app.run(${jsonString});`]);

    var dataToSend = ''
    python.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        dataToSend = data.toString() //<---How do I return this back to other functions?
        return callback(dataToSend)  //<---this is not returning back to other functions.
    })

    python.stderr.on('data', (data)=>{
            console.log(`stderr: ${data}`)
        })
    }

module.exports = { run_python_script };
```

=====================================================================
***This is the file that calls the "Child.js" file above where I want to receive the data from Python back...***

```
const Child = require('./Child.js');

const callback = (x)=>{return x} //<--simply returns what's put in

let company_data = {
    "industry": "Financial Services",
    "revenue": 123456789
}
jsonString = JSON.stringify(company_data);

let result = ''
result = Child.run_python_script(jsonString, callback) //<-- I want the results from python to be stored here so I can use it elsewhere. 

console.log(result) //<--this returns "undefined".  Data isn't coming back
```

Comment: Did you pass a callback function when invoking the script? Like: `run_python_script(function callback(receivedData) { console.log({ receivedData }) })`

Comment: Yes @RaynalGobel. Console log works in the callback function, but I want the actual data.  My callback function is: function callback(x){ return x}

Comment: just in case someone is using IPC and JSON serialization, what I observed is that it sends message from Child-to-Parent but not Parent-to-Child using `send()` function. When I used `fork` instead of `spawn`, it started sending messages in both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to spawn the Python process asynchronously, then you can use [`spawnSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawnsynccommand-args-options) instead of `spawn` to directly get an object containing its `stdout` and `stderr` as strings:

```js
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process');
const python = spawnSync('python3', ['-c', `print("hello"); assert False`], { encoding: "utf8" });

// Access stdout
console.log(python.stdout)

// Access stderr
console.log(python.stderr)
```

Comment: Thanks @peter Y!  This worked as well and is so much simpler than wrapping it in a promise.

Answer (score 0):

***I figured this out.  I wrapped the entire spawn routine in a Promise***

```
// child.js

function run_python_script(jsonString){

    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
        // spawn new child process to call the python script
        const {spawn} = require('child_process');
    
        const python = spawn('python3', ["-c",`from apps import python_app; python_app.run(${jsonString});`])

        var dataToSend = ''
        python.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            dataToSend = data.toString()
        })

        python.stderr.on('data', (data)=>{
            console.log(`stderr: ${data}`)
            reject(new Error(`stderr occured`))
        })

        python.on('close', (code)=>{
            if (code !=0){
                reject(new Error(`error code: ${code}`))
            }else{
                resolve(dataToSend)
            }
        })
    })

    return promise
}

module.exports = { run_python_script };
```

============================================================================
***And here is the parent function which calls the child function above:***

```
//Parent.js

const Child = require('./Child.js');

var data = {
    "industry": "Financial Services",
    "revenue": 12345678
}

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);

var result = ''
Child.run_python_script(jsonString).then(returnedData => {
    var result = returnedData;
    console.log(result)
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```